# Share artefacts between runner and different stages

Tags: docker, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the Mac Mini with to runners which is connected to Gitlab Ci, one in Docker and one direct, also the yaml file which is used in Gitlab Ci, and I try to build the android inside Docker runner in step build, but I need to see the artifacts from it in the host not in Docker, I've tried different steps but seems wrong. Here is the part of my last yaml file where I tried to specify the artifacts:

```
image: 
stage: build
script:
 - bash production.sh
artifacts:
  name: "android "
  expire_in: 3 days
  paths:
    - platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
dependencies: []
cache:
  policy: pull
  key: "android-builder-${CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION}"
  paths:
    - .yarn/
    - node_modules/
    - .gradle/wrapper/
    - .gradle/caches/
    - plugins/
only:
 - master

build android stay:
<<: *build_android_definition
variables:
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_BRANDING: default

# Bundled release package for easy deployment (for production deployment)
release package:
stage: release
script:
  - mkdir -p android
  - mkdir -p ios
  - mv platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/* android/
  - mv platforms/ios/build/* ios/  
dependencies:
  - build android app-store stay
artifacts:
  name: "client publish package ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
  expire_in: 1 mos
  paths:
    - android
    - ios
only:
  - master


# Automatically publish to the Playstore
publish android:
stage: publish
script:
  - fastlane supply --apk ....
  - echo Maybe even prepare some text for the user to show the instructions what have to be done to publish this using the artifacts that came out the release stuff!
tags:
  - macOS
only:
  - master
dependencies:
  - build android app-store stay

So i need to copy the platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/ which is in docker runner to the host slave.
```